# DateTime Format yyyy-mm-dd 24hr

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, .net-core, date-format

How to format a DateTime as follows?

yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss in 24 hr format

example

2001-03-16 14:45:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

For example:

`DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")`

Comment: You don't "escape" the colons in any way. So they represent the time separator string of the current culture. If the format provider is `new CultureInfo("bn-IN")` (Bangla (India)) for example, it will become `"2001-03-16 14.45.00"`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I had no idea. I thought those separators were literals. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `HH` format to get the hour in 24h, for sample:

```
string dateFormated = dateTimeObj.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
```

also use `MM` to get the month in 2 chars. You can take a look at [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).