# DateTime.TryParseExact returns false for MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

Following code returns `false` for me and I just can't figure out what am I doing wrong.

```
var localDateTimeString = "03/24/2016 21:05"; // subject.Substring(0, 16);

DateTime localDateTime;
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(
    localDateTimeString,
    "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm",
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
    DateTimeStyles.None,
    out localDateTime)) return false;
```

Format is fixed 16 char string, always 2 digits for days, month, minutes and hour. 4 digits for year.

But this code returns false, how can I fix this?

Comment: it should be `HH` not `hh`

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819538/datetime-format-yyyy-mm-dd-24hr?rq=1

Comment: @Nkosi Dupe yes, (and I am also biased as I answered this question) but I'd say the answers and question here are better than the previous question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DateTime Format yyyy-mm-dd 24hr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819538/datetime-format-yyyy-mm-dd-24hr)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short version it should be `HH` not `hh`. Unless the single digit hours (0 to 9) are returned as a single digit; in that case you should use `H`.

---

From [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

> - `HH`: The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
> - `hh`: The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
> - `H`: The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.
> - `h`: The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.

Essentially change your format from:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm"
```

To:

```
"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct format should be `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm`

```
if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(
                    localDateTimeString,
                    "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm",
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                    DateTimeStyles.None,
                    out localDateTime))
```