# string to DateTime(date)

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a string i recieved from my webservice into a DateTime so i can look if the date of that datetime is today or not.

I looked a bit and found on msdn and stackoverflow that these possibilities should work, they do not work for me for some reason.

```
string starttime = obj.TIME; //time i get from webservice = "02/14/2017 00:00:00"
DateTime startTimeCon = DateTime.Parse(starttime);
DateTime startTimeCon2 = Convert.ToDateTime(starttime);
```

error:

The string is not recognised as a valid DateTime

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you have different culture in your system.

Use `ParseExact()` instead of `Parse()`:

```
DateTime startTimeCon = DateTime.ParseExact(starttime, 
                                            "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

`HH` used for 24 hours, you can use `hh` for 12 hours

Also, you can set appropriate culture in `Parse()`:

```
DateTime startTimeCon = DateTime.Parse(starttime, neededCulture);
```

Comment: Or for more information on the hour formats see my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42677058/4631427). The answer also links to the MSDN page with them all.

Comment: This indeed works, thnx, i used this "DateTime endTimeCon = DateTime.ParseExact(starttime, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);" any quick info on the "CultureInfo.InvariantCulture"?

Comment: @sansactions, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396